# How to read/decipher the percent % in a bond's interest versus coupon rate question or example

Tags: bonds, interest, yield

I was studying about bonds, more so accreted/coupon bonds that were discounted. As far as I know and believe to be true is that when a question says:

1) Q. ["Mr. Dancer purchases a 5-percent corporate bond with 10 years to maturity at 80. What would Mr. Dancer’s annual reported income on this bond be?"](https://www.dummies.com/test-prep/series-7/how-to-calculate-accretion-and-amortization-on-the-series-7-exam/)

A.You need to take the $200 difference and divide it by 10 years to get $20. Mr. Dancer’s reported income would be $70 ($50 interest plus $20 accretion).

**The % is the annual interest**, but when I came across another question from somewhere else

2) Q. ["A customer buys a 5% municipal bond with 10 years left to maturity in the secondary market priced at 90 to yield 6.32%. After taking taxes into consideration, the customer's yield will be:"](https://www.studyblue.com/?src_url=https://www.studyblue.com/notes/note/n/tax-and-tax-shelters-chapter-8-series-7/deck/20722704#flashcard/flip/20722704) I believe that the second one mentioned is wrong. Is that correct to say the second one is wrong? The answer for the second says this:

A. "The return on this bond has 2 components: the 5% coupon rate and the 1% annual earning of the discount (10 point discount accreted over 10 years = 1 point or 1% per year gain). While the 5% coupon is not taxed, the 1% annual gain is taxed as interest income received. For someone in the 30% tax bracket, .3% of the 1% annual gain goes to tax, and .7% of the return is kept after tax. Thus, the after tax return is about 5.7%. This is a very difficult question."

Do you see what I am saying: the first question says 5% corporate bond, the second question says 5% municipal bond, but the two different sources identify them as different things. I thought the percentage before the term bond is the annual interest like question 1 says.

Please help,

Thank you

Comment: Yes, they both describe bonds that pay 5% annual interest. Can you be more specific on which part is confusing? Are you saying that the _yield_ of the second bond is wrong? Or is the after tax analysis throwing you off?

Comment: Hi, so the first one is saying 5% corporate, and this 5% is referring to 5% x $1000 of annual interest. The coupon for this is $20 per year (1000- 800)/10. The other one is 5% municipal, but it uses that 5% to compute the coupon, unlike the prior one. Shouldn't the coupon for the second one be (1000-900)/10 and the annual interest should be $50 like the other one?

Comment: I think you're confusing coupon and discount. They both pay $50/year in interest (coupon), but the corporate bond was bought at a 20% discount, so there's additional "income" of $20/year. The municipal bond was bought at a 10% discount for $10/year of additional "income".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both describe bonds that pays 5% annual interest (i.e. $50/year for a $1,000 bond), but the second is asking about the income *after taxes*. It's meant to illustrate that the *interest* from a municipal bond is not taxable (at least not at the Federal level in the US), but the $10/year gain from buying it at a discount is.

In the first example, *all* of the income (the $50 coupon and the $20 discount) is taxable, so the after-tax income would just be the income times (1 - the tax rate).

Also, the "6.32% yield" mentioned in the second example is correct, but it's irrelevant for the specific question asked.

Answer (score 0):

The second question includes a yield-to-maturity calculation result of 6.32%.

The first question doesn't include a yield-to-maturity calculation result.

Comment: I thought the CY should be < YTM for a discount bond.

Comment: The bond coupons are 5%. Bond coupons are actual cash flow.

Comment: Thank you but I meant current yield should be less than yield to maturity right?

Comment: current yield is the annual income in dollars / Market Price and in my book, it is saying if a bond trades at a Discount, Coupon < CY < YTM. I believe the CY is referring to the current yield, which would be $60/$900, but that is greater than the YTM.

Comment: I see, there is a terminology of "current yield" that is not yield-to-maturity. But the current yield is the cash flow, or coupon payment, divided by the bond market price. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/currentyield.asp . So that's 50/900 or 5.56% .

Comment: Ok, so it does not include accretion, I wonder if this is because the $10 extra from accretion is added to the cost basis as a appreciation of the bond and the bond holder does not actually receive CASH payments from it? Therefore, annual income from dollars really means coupon payment, and that is the only way the CY < YTM makes sense here.

Comment: yes, that makes sense, but as far as the current yield equation goes I am just going to put $50 / $900 (= 5.56%), because that is the coupon payment / current market price and that makes the logic of CY < YTM for a coupon discount bond. See if we do $50 + $10 / $900 we get 6.7%, we want CY to be < YTM (6.32%).

Comment: With the discounted bond, the annual income is more than the coupon payment. But the "current yield" is coupon divided by market price as 50/900 or 5.56% while the given yield-to-maturity is 6.32%

Comment: Therefore the pass perfect book should not be saying the current yield is the annual income payments and be more specific and say coupon payments.

Comment: Here is a simple calculation of general interest: 100 - 90 = 10; 10 / 10 = 1; 5 + 1 = 6; 6 / 90 = 6.67%. That's 6.67% versus the given yield-to-maturity of 6.32%. But we know that yield-to-maturity includes a compounding element. Here is a website that has an inverse of the simple calculation: http://www.kbhscape.com/bond.htm .